# DLR url for an SMS Gateway

Tags: python, sms

I have a General Question and I'm sorry if this question isn't allowed here for being so general, but I started using an SMS Gateway and they gave me their API documentation. The documentation is pretty basic and does not give a lot of information except what you should put in the POST request url and body.

In their body, there is a parameter called dlr: and they put this as an example: `"dlr-url": "https://yourdomain.com/dlr"`

I looked up DLR online and found out that it is an endpoint that you send data to after sending the SMS (correct me if I'm wrong).

What can I do with this DLR url? And how can I create it?

PS: I use Python in my programming.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for the [Kaleyra API](https://globalmessaging.kaleyra.com/support/solutions/articles/3000091767-delivery-url-for-sms-api)

> **What is Delivery URL?**
> DLRURL is the URL from which you can get the delivery reports if requested through an API. To request such delivery reports, you need to pass "DLRURL" parameter in the API URL.

So you use this if you want to be notified about whether the SMS was delivered successfully, and get other details about the delivery. The specifics will depend on the API.

The URL would normally point to a script that you write (you could use Flask to implement this in Python), which takes some action based on the delivery status. It could log the status information, notify an administrator of a failure, etc.